# Removing an Index altogehter from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If i declare this

```
var data = [];
data [300] = 1;
data [600] = 1;
data [783] = 1;
```

I have an array of length 784 but with only 3 defined items within it.

Since splice(300,1) would delete the item and the index but would also shift every consecutive position, how can i delete the object in the index 300 from the array without altering the order of the array so when i use

```
for(var x in data)
```

it can correctly iterate only 2 times, on the indexes  600 and 783?

i tried using `data[300] = undefined` but the index 300 was still iterated over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `delete`:

```
delete data[300];
```

This sets the value of the index to be undefined, but doesn't modify the element index itself.

See more about the delete operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Answer (score 4):

dsg's answer will certainly work if you're going to use an array.  But, if your data is going to be as sparse as it is, I wonder if a plain Javascript object might be a better choice for such sparse data where you never want the index/key to change.  Arrays are optimized for consecutive sequences of data starting with an index of 0 and for iterating over a sequence of values.  And, they keep track of a `.length` property of the highest index used minus one.

But, since you aren't really doing any of that and given the way you are storing data, you aren't able to use any of the useful features of an array.  So, you could do this instead with a plain Javascript object:

```
var data = {};
data [300] = 1;
data [600] = 1;
data [783] = 1;

delete data[300];
```

This would create an object with three properties and then would delete one of those properties.

You can then iterate over the properties on an object like this:

```
for (var prop in data) {
    console.log(data[prop]);
}
```

A couple things to remember: 1) The property names are always strings so your numbers would show us as "600" in the `prop` variable in the above iteration.  2) Iterating with the `for/in` technique does not guarantee any order of the properties iterated.  They could come in any order since properties on an object have no innate order.

Comment: It is true that the array is sparsely populated, nevertheless honestly i did it this way because i don't know if you can  iterate over this specific set of properties of an object without knowing the keys beforehand. Can you?

Comment: @NicolasZ - I added an example of how you iterate properties of an object.

Comment: Fantastic! thank you for the orientation, i'll do the switch. I will mark dsg answer as accepted though as it is the one that answers specifically the question.

Comment: +1 only other thing that could also be of use to the OP to know is about how the properties returned from a for..in can be returned in arbitrary order

Comment: @dsg - added a note about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can `delete` that element from the array:

```
delete data[300];
```

The full example:

```js
var data = [];
data [300] = 1;
data [600] = 1;
data [783] = 1;

delete data[300];

var result = "";
for (var x in data) {
    result += "<div>" + x + "</div>"; 
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="output" />
```

Comment: Rendering `innerHTML` inside a loop is not a good idea in terms of performance. Create a string instead, and when the loop is over, output it.

Comment: That was not meant to be part of the example, just that I need a way to output results in the inline StackOverflow examples, the console does not show up here.

Comment: No need for the console: `var t=''; for(...){ t += '<div...'; } document....innerHTML = t;`